# Highcharts: Adding specific tooltip information in drill down series

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, drilldown

I'm using Highcharts to create Pie charts with drilldowns, my drilldowns work fine but cannot figure out how to put specific data into the tooltips for each slice on the drilldowns.

My drilldowns look like this:

```
drilldown: {
        series: [
            {id: 'Client A',
                data: [{name: 'Prep', y: 95.35},{name: 'Pros', y: 120.07}]
            },{id: 'Client B',
                data: [{name: 'Prep', y: 19.9},{name: 'Pros', y: 5.63}]
            }
        ]
    }
```

How would I add in a drill down for each slice, something like this:

```
{id: 'Client A', data: [{name: 'Prep', y: 95.35, tooltip: {tooltip html here}},{name: 'Pros', y: 120.07, tooltip: {tooltip html here}}]}...
```

Is that possible on drilldown slices?

Comment: Yes, it should work. I would change from `tooltip` to `my_tooltip` or something similar. Otherwise Highcharts may try to utilize your property in some unexpected way. After that, use `tooltip.formatter`  and check if point contains your property: `if(this.point.options.my_tooltip) { ... } else { ... }`.